# Flatten and unwrap optionals in Double dimensional array

Tags: swift, option-type, flatmap

The following code does the job.

```
var array:[[Int?]] = [[1,2,3,nil],[1,2,3,nil]]
var flattened = array.flatMap{$0}.flatMap{$0}
// flattened is of type [Int]
```

But two `flatMap` one after another doesn't make the code easily readable if find. How would you write this in a cleaner way ?

Comment: Try .map{$0}.flatMap{$0}

Comment: This will return an array of optionals.

Comment: it will not get much shorter or easier to understand than that, if someone knows what flatMap does it is the best solution - if someones does not, he should read up on it since every other solution would be equally confusing.

Comment: The first flatMap can be replaced by `flatten()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatMap<S : SequenceType>(transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> S) rethrows -> [S.Generator.Element]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_7flatMapu__Rq_S_qd__S__Fq_FzFzqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7Elementqd__GSaqqqd__S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_)
is a combination of `map()` and `flatten()`:

> `s.flatMap(transform)`
>   is equivalent to
>   `Array(s.map(transform).flatten())`

You are using `flatMap()` with the "identity transform" `{ $0 }`
to concatenate the arrays; this can be simplified
by using `flatten()` directly:

```
let flattened = array.flatten().flatMap { $0 }
```